# how to use boost graph as a member variable

Tags: c++, boost-graph

I am almost new to boost-graph library.
How to declare `graph` as a member variable?

```
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS,
                          boost::vecS,
                          boost::undirectedS> Graph;
class myclass{
private:
    Graph graph;
void connect(const int N)
{
    // Graph graph(N); // make it local
    // or
    graph(N); //error
    for (size_t i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = i + 1; j < N; j++)
        {
            if (adj[i][j] != 0)
                boost::add_edge(i, j, graph);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit**:
maybe we can make an instance of graph and pass it to the class

```
Graph graph(N);
myclass.set_params(graph);
```

Is it the only option?

Comment: `graph(N);` --> `graph = Graph(N);`?

Comment: You already have `graph` defined as a member variable. Your error is on the line where you try to manipulate the member variable. It's tough to tell what that line should be since you did not tell us what that line should do.

Comment: I should put an "or" in file after Graph graph(N);

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> graph(N); //error
> ```

That is not valid since `graph` is not callable; and you can't construct a member variable outside the constructor.

You will need to copy/move assign it, or use whatever member functions `Graph` has to set whatever properties you need.

I suggest [picking up a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)!

Comment: I was looking for a valid way to construct it inside the class instead of building it outside and then pass it to the class.

Comment: That's where the book comes in: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2e97da379a591c64 (three ways to [re-]initialize)